# Accessibility: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called when cell selected with voiceover

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, voiceover

I have a very simple UITableView with a custom class for my cells. The cells consist of various labels (isAccessibility=NO).

I have an accessibilityValue set for each cell, and isAccessibility=YES/enabled in Storyboard for each cell.

When the user double-taps to select the cell...nothing happens. didSelectRowAtIndexPath, which contains my navigation logic, does not get called. At other locations in my app that use segues work fine, with the same cell setup.

What am I doing wrong that would make didSelectRowAtIndexPath not get called?

Edit: this code works fine without Voiceover. Tapping the cell calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath as expected. Voiceover simply isn't triggering didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Going to be super hard to troubleshoot without some idea of the code you're using where. Have you properly connected all your IBOutlets? Have you stepped through and inspected properties using the debugger?

Comment: Yes, works fine without Voiceover. My issue is that Voiceover isn't causing didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get called; I assume this is related to my accessibility setup in the storyboard; there's not much to my code.

Comment: What about the delegates? Are they set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, the TableView delegate is connected in IB (it works fine without voiceover).

Comment: Can you still select the cells with the VO cursor? What does the VO inspector in the simulator say? Can you upload a sample project reproducing the behavior?

Comment: I can select the cells, the VO reads my accessibilityValue properly - and repeats the accessibilityValue when I double-tap instead of selecting. Let me try the VO inspector in the Simulator; I didn't realize that existed.

Comment: Are you sure VO is focusing one of your cells, and not a TextView or other UIControl within your cell?

Comment: OP: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @AceGreen honestly I have no recollection of ever asking this question, im sorry

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem.

Fix below work for me

> cell.isAccessibilityElement = YES;